# Android Studio Git works weird I think?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I am using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4. I'm using Git and committing a state. And then add some code and I want to return to where I was (before I entered the new code). When I checkout it does nothing. Even if I restarted Android Studio. And when I Reset Current Branch to Here.. initially it does nothing but if I restart the Android Studio new code is gone(as I wanted). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command to remove the newly added but not commited code is:

```
git stash
```

It will remove the unstaged codes and return the code-base to the last commit.

We normally use 'git checkout' to move around between different commits.

If you want to do this process without command, you will need to "Rollback changes". The keyboard shortcut for macos for this is: option + command + z. [image: Shortcut for Rollback changes]

[image: Rollback changes in the whole project]

Comment: how can i use it without console command?

Comment: I have updated my answer for "without console command" case. Please check the corresponding command for your environment if you use any other OS than mac.